# Function won't run and not sure how to convert string

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

So, I'm trying to create a program that takes user input, runs functions against parameters to determine what percentage is output, and then combines all the earned percentages together before multiplying them against the total profit (first box they input info into) to give a number. 
Ex: 15000 profit, qualifies for 10% after the parameters are met, output $1500. In short, its a commission calculator for my organization that I'm building in my down time to make life easier.

I've got most of it built, GUI runs, but when I input numbers and click calculate I get this error and I'm unsure how to resolve it.

**Edited to add code for GUI and button

> > Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> >     "C:\Users\word2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter__init__.py",
> >     line 1883, in **call**
> >         return self.func(*args)   File "C:/Users/word2/PycharmProjects/Commission2/main.py", line 75, in
> >     calculatetotal
> >         return grossc() + epc() + sprint_elite() * grossp.get()   File "C:/Users/word2/PycharmProjects/Commission2/main.py", line 55, in
> >     grossc
> >         if gross < 5500: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'int'

Code:

```
    from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


root = Tk()
root.title("Commission Calculator")


# Defining String variables to call user input

grossp = IntVar()
emergingp = IntVar()
pp = IntVar()
sc = IntVar()
pay = IntVar()

# Function to call user input and display it in the "Payout" Column


def calculategp():
    try:
        value1 = int(grossp.get())
        return value1
    except ValueError:
        return "error"


def calculateep():
    try:
        value2 = int(emergingp.get())
        return value2
    except ValueError:
        return "error"


def calculatese():
    try:
        value3 = sc.get()
        value4 = pp.get()
        value5 = True
        value6 = 0
        if value3 >= 65:
            return True
        if value4 >= 70:
            return True
        if value3 and value4 is True:
            return value5
        if value3 and value4 is False:
            return value6
    except ValueError:
        return value6


def grossc():
    if gross < 5500:
        return 0.0
    if gross > 5500 < 10000:
        return 0.01
    if gross > 10000 < 15000:
        return 0.03
    if gross > 15000:
        return 0.05


def epc():
    if emerging <= 6:
        return 0.01

def sprint_elite():
    if se is True:
        return 0.03


def calculatetotal():
    return grossc() + epc() + sprint_elite() * grossp.get()


gross = calculategp
emerging = calculateep
se = calculatese()
# Defining Labels
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=N)


# Labels for input boxes


GP = Label(root, padx=5, pady=5, text="Gross Profit")
EP = Label(root, padx=5, pady=5, text="Emerging Products")
Plus_premium = Label(root, padx=5, pady=5, text="Plus/Premium")
Sprint_complete = Label(root, padx=5, pady=5, text="Sprint Complete")
Pay = Label(root, padx=5, pady=5, text="Total Payout")

# Defining input box

grossp_entry = Entry(root, textvariable=grossp, width=20)
emergingp_entry = Entry(root, textvariable=emergingp, width=20)
pp_entry = Entry(root, textvariable=pp, width=20)
sc_entry = Entry(root, textvariable=sc, width=20)
pay_entry = Entry(root, width=20, textvariable=pay)

# Placing input boxes on grid

grossp_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
emergingp_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
pp_entry.grid(row=2, column=1)
sc_entry.grid(row=3, column=1)
pay_entry.grid(row=4, column=1)

# Putting labels on grid

GP.grid(row=0, column=0)
EP.grid(row=1, column=0)
Plus_premium.grid(row=2, column=0)
Sprint_complete.grid(row=3, column=0)
Pay.grid(row=4, column=0,)

# Creating button

btn = Button(root, width=10, height=2, text="Calculate", command=calculatetotal)

# Placing button on Grid

btn.grid(row=5, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code is assuming two variables or values are integers. One of those assumptions is false. Specifcially, `gross` isn't an integer.

Comment: Wait, how so? gross is tied to the calculategp function, which pulls from grossp. Grossp is an IntVar() that is pulled from the Entry when user inputs a number and hits calculate. What am i missing here? Ive been staring at this for hours and im not understanding where im failing.

Comment: @BlakeWord ***gross is tied to the calculategp function***... gross has only saved a reference to a function. You are missing the `()` for it to actually return any values by calling the function. That said once that is fixed then you have another potential problem when `error` is returned. This will cause the same error you are currently getting as well.

Comment: `gross = calculategp` is not the same as `gross = calculategp()`.

Comment: Oh my god and I even got it right on one of them! That fixed one error, but I'm still getting: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\word2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/word2/PycharmProjects/Commission2/main.py", line 75, in calculatetotal
    return grossc()+epc()+sprint_elite()*grossc()
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'float'

Comment: I'm not using float, so i'm not sure where the NoneType would be coming from, they should all be integers by the time the final calculation is called

Comment: If you use `print(grossc(), epc(), sprint_elite(), grossp.get())` in your `calculatetotal` function you will see where the problem is. Results `0.0 0.01 None 0`. This is one reason you need to take care how you write your if statements when returning data. `if se is True` is not happening here so nothing is returned and thus the value is None for `sprint_elite()`. That said you are using `return` in a function attached to a button. This will basically result in nothing happening as your button cannot do anything with a `return`.

Comment: I... am totally lost now. I'm not sure why they arent returning results now. An earlier version of this worked before I added the functions to calculate the percentage, where each box I could put a number and it would calculate it into payout. Then i tried to add functions to get the percentages and multiply them to get the total and it broke, and im not sure how anymore. So return and buttons cant work together? That means i gotta find out what can. Okay, thats a start.

Comment: @BlakeWord What do you think `calculatetotal` is doing here? Lets just say the math works without error. What do you think the return is doing? A tkinter button will not accept any return and the fact that your button is the only thing calling that function tells me this function is not doing anything useful until you remove that return and do something else with the math.

Comment: I thought return stored the integer. It seems that was wrong. So, remove the return, but the only other tkinter option I've been able to find is a lambda which im not fully understanding. What do you mean by do something else with the math? Like compact it into a simpler equation?

Comment: sorry for the huge amount of questions, this is literally the first thing ive ever built and i'm kinda learning as I go, I've already rebuilt the GUI on it two or three times in the process of learning as I broke things. Thanks a lot for chatting with me

Comment: @BlakeWord Well instead of using `return` simply assign the resulting value to a variable in the global name space. Then you can grab it and use it later for whatever you need. To be clear `return` does not store anything. Its only task is to return whatever value you give it to whatever called the function in the first place. If that is a variable name then the variable has the value stored but if that is say a tk Button then that return falls on deaf ears as it were.

Comment: Do you happen to have any other advice @Mike - SMT , I've been googling around and I'm not even finding anything that seems it would work for me to read and learn how to solve my problem?

Comment: I think the best advice we can give (well, _I_ can give) is to spend more time validating your assumptions about the code. Add some print statements or learn about pdb, and examine values of variables every step of the way. There's almost always a trail going back to some wrong assumptions. That, and remove about half the code. Start small, with a single input field, a couple of buttons, a label to show the result. Figure out how to get that working before adding more moving parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you use `print(grossc(), epc(), sprint_elite(), grossp.get())` in your `calculatetotal` function you will see where the problem is. Results `0.0 0.01 None 0`. This is one reason you need to take care how you write your if statements when returning data. `if se is True` is not happening here so nothing is returned and thus the value is None for `sprint_elite()`. That said you are using return in a function attached to a button. This will basically result in nothing happening as your button cannot do anything with a return.
2. You have if statements that return a value but if the condition is not met they don't return a value. Sometimes this is ok but in this case with your math a number must be returned or else the math will error out due to None.
3. Use `import tkinter as tk` instead of `*` this will help prevent overwriting other imports or functions/variables you write.
4. You have 2 problems with these 3 lines.

   ```
   gross = calculategp
   emerging = calculateep
   se = calculatese()
   ```

The first 2 lines are missing the `()`. That said these should be in the functions as it stands now they are run at the instant of the code being ran and are only ever going to have one value. So if you place them in the functions they belong to then they will return values at the time you press the button.

5. I did some general clean up on your code so let me know if something confuses you.

Based on all we talked about in the comments I have cleaned up your code a bit and it should be working how you expected now. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def calculategp():
    try:
        value1 = int(grossp.get())
        return value1
    except ValueError:
        return "error"


def calculateep():
    try:
        value2 = int(emergingp.get())
        return value2
    except ValueError:
        return "error"


def calculatese():
    try:
        value3 = sc.get()
        value4 = pp.get()
        value5 = True
        if value3 >= 65:
            return True
        if value4 >= 70:
            return True
        if value3 and value4 is True:
            return value5
        if value3 and value4 is False:
            return 0
    except ValueError:
        return 0


def grossc():
    gross = calculategp()
    if gross < 5500:
        return 0.0
    if gross > 5500 < 10000:
        return 0.01
    if gross > 10000 < 15000:
        return 0.03
    if gross > 15000:
        return 0.05


def epc():
    if calculateep() <= 6:
        return 0.01
    else:
        return 0


def sprint_elite():
    if calculatese() is True:
        print('True')
        return 0.03
    else:
        return 0


def calculatetotal():
    print(grossc(), epc(), sprint_elite(), grossp.get())
    pay.set(grossc() + epc() + sprint_elite() * grossp.get())


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Commission Calculator")
emergingp = tk.IntVar()
grossp = tk.IntVar()
pay = tk.IntVar()
pp = tk.IntVar()
sc = tk.IntVar()

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='n')

tk.Label(root, padx=5, pady=5, text="Gross Profit").grid(row=0, column=0)
tk.Label(root, padx=5, pady=5, text="Emerging Products").grid(row=1, column=0)
tk.Label(root, padx=5, pady=5, text="Plus/Premium").grid(row=2, column=0)
tk.Label(root, padx=5, pady=5, text="Sprint Complete").grid(row=3, column=0)
tk.Label(root, padx=5, pady=5, text="Total Payout").grid(row=4, column=0)
tk.Entry(root, textvariable=grossp, width=20).grid(row=0, column=1)
tk.Entry(root, textvariable=emergingp, width=20).grid(row=1, column=1)
tk.Entry(root, textvariable=pp, width=20).grid(row=2, column=1)
tk.Entry(root, textvariable=sc, width=20).grid(row=3, column=1)
tk.Entry(root, textvariable=pay, width=20).grid(row=4, column=1)

btn = tk.Button(root, width=10, height=2, text="Calculate", command=calculatetotal)
btn.grid(row=5, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: hey sorry it took me so long to get back to you, this is a personal pet project so with end of month and start of month I've been in meeting after meeting that had nothing to do with coding and no spare time. That was tremendously helpful! It still doesnt work exactly how I want it too, but thats okay because I gotta learn! Thanks for the clean up and all you did, I'm currently comparing your code to mine so I can understand functional differences, things you pointed out, and what cleaner code looks like. Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: Glad to help. Take some time to read PEP8 standars. This will help with clean coding.